# SQL request fails to retrieve data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve the `email` field from my database using the `id` associated with it:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".$userID."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

This query is always returning `NULL` and I can't work out why.

Have tested using a `var_dump` that `$userID` is indeed correct.

But when I use it with the hardcoded value instead of `$userID` it works fine:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '85' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Why isn't the `$userID` variable being passed to my query? Is there a way to pass this correctly?**

Edit:

Declaration of $userID as requested. var_dump of this variable works OK the line before the query2.

```
// Fetch ID for matching details
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$emailInput."' && `username` = '".$usernameInput."' ") or die(mysql_error());


        // Successful query - ID stored
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
        $userID = mysql_fetch_array($query);}

        var_dump($userID);
```

Both var_dumps output the following on the page:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "85" ["id"]=> string(2) "85" } NULL
```

Comment: var_dump($userID); and post the result

Comment: Hi Robert, yes I have done that as I said in the OP. It posts the correct result.

Comment: Francesca, Try storing the hole query on a var and dump it to see the result. And if Id is numeric you should not need the '' arround the 85

Comment: Show us where you declare $userID please

Comment: try `".$userID."` (that means passing the ID value as integer instead of string)

Comment: Post the output of echo $qry pls.... http://codepad.viper-7.com/aFyzU3

Comment: Id say the the fact that $userID is an array is your problem... Do `$userID['id']` instead in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id say the the fact that `$userID` is an array is your problem... Do `$userID['id']` instead in the query.

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '" . $userID['id'] . "' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing either double quotes or single quotes. because id is usually of data type int you are using twice which makes it a string value..

also PHP is  quite smart in recognizing variables and data types so u can use `"$userID"` or `"{$userID}"` without concatination..

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a concatenation problem , if the $userid is string its should be fine , but if its an integer or double..etc it will be dealt with as a string

if its an integer try :

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ".$userID) or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ".$userID['0']) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

so, the problem is that your `$userID` is not **85** or a simple number but it's an array and you are still trying to concatenate it in the query.

The problem is somewhere else in your code, probably where you set `$userID`

Here goes the solution:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = " . $userID['id']) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $userID ") or die(mysql_error());
```